# ¿Como cambiar de variables en un bucle en VBA?

Tags: variables, bucles

Hola pido ayuda para solucionar el cambio de variable en un bucle ejemp. trato 
de cambiar la variable AAver a AAver1, AAver2, AAver3... AAver9 una vez cada 
ciclo. De antemano Gracias.

```
    For i = 1 To 10
    ActiveCell.Value = AAver + (Abs(AMax - AAver))
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que crear una variable fuera de tu ciclo tipo string y concatenarle la variable que tienes en  tu ciclo de la siguiente forma.

```
Dim AAVer As String
        For i As Integer = 1 To 5
            AAVer = "AAVer " & i
        Next
```